# Unit testing rest services without authentication

Tags: spring-security, restful-authentication

I'm using jersey with spring security.
I want to test my rest services with Junit but there is an authentication problem.
My project services are secured with spring security and client should be authenticated.
I want to know if there is a way (or there are ways) to prevent authentication for my test or something like browser do for remembering client and run multi tests.

```
Client client = Client.create();

//I usually write some code here to authenticate client.

WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/SomeResources");

ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Comment: Maybe you can use preemptive authentication: you forge a correct HTTP request with credentials (for instance with Apache HTTP components) in your tests.